# How to use -*-_DB_SHORT_LIVED_SESSIONS configuration setting

Tags: python, django, celery

What does `"-*-"` represent in `-*-_DB_SHORT_LIVED_SESSIONS (Django-specific)` Celery setting.

I need short-lived sessions but I don't understand what am I supposed to replace `-*-.`
I can't find it in the documentation neither

The Django-specific doc is here:
[Django-specific Celery settings doc](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#latentcall-django-admonition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you shouldn't be using this anymore.

See https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5819

From this Github issue I raised:

*you should use the lowercase database_short_lived_sessions instead*. This also applies for Django.